# If $A=\begin{bmatrix}2&1&1\\0&1&0\\1&1&2\end{bmatrix}$, find $A^8-5A^7+7A^6-3A^5+A^4-5A^3+8A^2-2A+I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $A=\begin{bmatrix}2&1&1\\0&1&0\\1&1&2\end{bmatrix}$, find $A^8-5A^7+7A^6-3A^5+A^4-5A^3+8A^2-2A+I$

**Attempt $1:$** $A=I+B$, where $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&0&0\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$

$B^n$ comes out to be $2^{n-1}B$

After that I tried doing $A^8=(I+B)^8$ and then opening RHS with binomial. But it didn't help.

**Attempt $2:$** Finding characteristic equation and putting $A$ in it. It didn't help either.

The equation I got here is $A^3-5A^2+7A-3I=0$

**Note:** Concept of minimal polynomial is not in syllabus. Also, if we can do this without characteristic polynomial, that would be great.

Comment: What are the characteristic and minimal polynomial of $A$?

Comment: your attempt two definitely should help since the characterstic polynomial will be of degree $3$ and you can use that to reduce the $8$ to $3.$

Comment: By the way, I don't think $B^n$ is what you claim it is (for $n \ge 3$). I'd expect $2^n$ where you have $n$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thanks. I have made an edit.

Comment: @dezdichado I tried squaring and cubing. It didn't work.

Comment: Actually, I think the first attempt is not such a bad idea either. If you have a few minutes, expand all $A^n$ with the respective binomial formulas and see what happens.

Comment: Do you want an answer using the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @insipidintegrator that would help, thanks.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg $A^8=I+8B+^8C_2B^2+...$ and $A^7=I+7B+^7C_2B^2...$. If I replace $B^2$ with $2B$, I get $A^8=I+8B+8!B+...$ and $A^7=I+7B+7!B+...$

Comment: Well that would lead to a result eventually, using $B^n =2^{n-1}B$, one just adds a lot of binomial coefficients. But the approach with characteristic polynomial seems shorter now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have, $$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&1&1\\0&1&0\\1&1&2\end{bmatrix}$$

According to Caley-Hamilton Theorem,
$$|A - \lambda I| = 0$$

So we have,
$$A - \lambda I = \begin{bmatrix}2&1&1\\0&1&0\\1&1&2\end{bmatrix} - \lambda \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2 - \lambda&1&1\\0&1 - \lambda &0\\1&1&2 - \lambda\end{bmatrix}$$

Now,
$$|A - \lambda I|  = 0 $$$$\implies \begin{vmatrix}2 - \lambda&1&1\\0&1 - \lambda &0\\1&1&2 - \lambda\end{vmatrix}  = 0$$$$\implies \lambda^3 - 5\lambda^2 + 7 \lambda - 3 = 0\tag{1}$$

Now, since every matrix is the root of its Eigen matrix, we have:
$$A^3 - 5A^2 + 7A  - 3 = 0 \tag{2}$$

Now consider,
$$A^8-5A^7+7A^6-3A^5+A^4-5A^3+8A^2-2A+I$$
$$ = (A^3- 5A^2  + 7A - 3) (A^5 + A) + (A^2 + A + I) $$

Using equation $(2)$ this equation will be changed into,
$$ (0) (A^5 + A) + (A^2 + A + I) $$
$$ =  (A^2 + A + I)$$

Now put values of $A^2, A$ and $I$, it will be done!

---

Factorization step:
$$A^8-5A^7+7A^6-3A^5+A^4-5A^3+8A^2-2A+I$$
$$A^5(A^3-5A^2+7A-3) +A^4-5A^3+8A^2-2A+I$$
$$A^5(A^3-5A^2+7A-3) +A^4-5A^3+7A^2 + A^2 - 3A + A+I$$
$$A^5(A^3-5A^2+7A-3) +A^4-5A^3+7A^2- 3A  + A^2 + A+I$$
$$A^5\underbrace{(A^3-5A^2+7A-3)} +A\underbrace{(A^3-5A^2+7A - 3)} + A^2 + A+I$$
$$(A^5 + A)(A^3-5A^2+7A-3) + (A^2 + A+I)$$

Comment: Hi. How did you factorize?

Comment: Yooo beat me to it! @aarbee, my hint should answer your query

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$A^5(A^3-5A^2+7A-3I)+A(A^3-5A^2+7A-3I)+A^2+A+I=\cdots$$

Comment: The polynomial to be evaluated can be nicely grouped to exploit the characteristic polynomial. I doubt a more efficient way exists.

Comment: Thank you.......

Answer (score 1):

Following your **attempt 1** and using
$$\begin{cases}
A-I &= B\\
B^2 &= 2B
\end{cases}$$ you get that
$A^2-4A + 3I=0$, i.e. that $q(A)=0$ where $q(x) = x^2-4x +3$. You want to get $p(A)$ where $p(x)=x^8-5x^7+7x^6-3x^5+x^4-5x^3+8x^2-2x+1$.
Performing the [long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) of $p$ by $q$ you get
$$p(x) = (x^6-x^5+x^2-x+1)q(x) + 5x-2.$$
Hence $$p(A)= 5A-2I=5B + 3I=\begin{bmatrix}8&5&5\\0&3&0\\5&5&8\end{bmatrix}$$

*Note: when you'll learn the minimum polynomial, you'll be able to see that $q$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$. However, the notion is not required for the question.*

Comment: Wonderful method, thanks